# Divide the results of two select queries and add that result to another per each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With the help of astentx, he showed me how to calculate the percentage of two select queries that bring back a count with the below query

```
select
100.0 *
count(
    case when ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C'
    then 1
    end
)
   /
  nullif(count(
case when PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'
then 1
end
), 0) as PERCENT_COMPLETE_BY_LINE_PROGRES_TYPE_
FROM dbo.PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
WHERE ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C'
or PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'
```

Now how do I add the above the below query so it adds another column to each distinct row with PERCENT_COMPLETE_BY_LINE_PROGRES_TYPE_

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_, PROJECT_NUMBER_,
CASE
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'A' THEN 'NOT IN MODEL'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'B' THEN 'ROUGHED IN'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C' THEN 'PARTIAL CHECK'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'D' THEN 'READY FOR FINAL CHECK'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'E' THEN '100% COMPLETE'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = '0' THEN 'ISSUE FOR CONSTRUCTION'
END AS PROGRESS_PER_LINE_
FROM PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
WHERE PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'
ORDER BY ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_
```

This returns the below data:

```
ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_   PROJECT_NUMBER_ PROGRESS_PER_LINE_
A                       PJ001234        NOT IN MODEL
B                       PJ001234        ROUGHED IN
C                       PJ001234        PARTIAL CHECK
D                       PJ001234        READY FOR FINAL CHECK
```

If I take out the distinct in the above query I have multiple lines per progress level. I want to add the the results above another column at the end with PERCENT_COMPLETE_BY_LINE_PROGRES_TYPE_ that I get from the first query. So the end product would look like this:

```
ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_   PROJECT_NUMBER_ PROGRESS_PER_LINE_  PERCENT_COMPLETE_BY_LINE_PROGRES_
A                       PJ001234          NOT IN MODEL                  23%
B                       PJ001234          ROUGHED IN                    17%
C                       PJ001234          PARTIAL CHECK                 40%
D                       PJ001234          READY FOR FINAL CHECK         20%
```

Thanks in advance for any help, very appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once. [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a02e8586a81308ac32adff27cd68d0c4) Code here

```
SELECT ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_
,PROJECT_NUMBER_
,PROGRESS_PER_LINE_
,100 * count(1) / SUM(sum(1)) OVER () AS PERCENT_COMPLETE_BY_LINE_PROGRES_
FROM (
SELECT ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_
    ,PROJECT_NUMBER_
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'A'
            THEN 'NOT IN MODEL'
        WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'B'
            THEN 'ROUGHED IN'
        WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C'
            THEN 'PARTIAL CHECK'
        WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'D'
            THEN 'READY FOR FINAL CHECK'
        WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'E'
            THEN '100% COMPLETE'
        WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = '0'
            THEN 'ISSUE FOR CONSTRUCTION'
        END AS PROGRESS_PER_LINE_
FROM PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES o
WHERE PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'
) a
GROUP BY ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_
,PROJECT_NUMBER_
,PROGRESS_PER_LINE_
ORDER BY ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just switch your `DISTINCT` to a `GROUP BY`, then add the `COUNT` calculation.**

`DISTINCT` is the same as grouping by all columns.

Note that you do not now need the conditional count because it applies to each grouping separately, you can use a standard `COUNT(*)`. You do need to change the overall `COUNT` to a windowed `SUM(COUNT(*))`

```sql
SELECT
  p.ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_,
  p.PROJECT_NUMBER_,
  CASE p.ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_
    WHEN 'A' THEN 'NOT IN MODEL'
    WHEN 'B' THEN 'ROUGHED IN'
    WHEN 'C' THEN 'PARTIAL CHECK'
    WHEN 'D' THEN 'READY FOR FINAL CHECK'
    WHEN 'E' THEN '100% COMPLETE'
    WHEN '0' THEN 'ISSUE FOR CONSTRUCTION'
    END AS PROGRESS_PER_LINE_,
  100.0 * COUNT(*) / NULLIF(SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (), 0) AS PERCENT_COMPLETE_BY_LINE_PROGRES_TYPE_
FROM PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES p
WHERE p.PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'
GROUP BY p.ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_, p.PROJECT_NUMBER_
ORDER BY p.ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_;
```